# Vim - Backspace moves cursor

Tags: vim, macvim

When in select mode (used mouse to select some text) if I delete a chunk of text with the backspace the postion of the cursor moves backwards a few places which is very annoying. I know I should probably never be using the mouse but....its annoying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With me, a visual selection done with the mouse, is (obviously) *not* deleted with backspace, but that's probably due the fact that I'm not on a Mac (doesn't a Mac have fewer keys in the delete/backspace department?)

You might get mileage from this type of mapping:

```
:snoremap <BS> x
```

It works like a charm with me. If you feel like being adventurous, you might map it to `<Del>` even when your physical keyboard doesn't have that key :).

Note that in order to prevent the 'cut' text from being yanked in the default register, change the mapping to be `"_x` instead of plain `x`

---

<sub>On my PCs, mouse selection actually starts a Visual Mode selection, due to the fact that I have `behave xterm` in $MYVIMRC, so I needed to do this:</sub>

```
:vnoremap <BS> x
```

If you want to override the select behaviour back to the default, use

```
:se selectmode=mouse
```